# TypeError: Form is Null on Button in Admin toolbar

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, javascript, jform, error-reporting

I am receiving

> TypeError: form is null

in the browser console when I select a custom button added to a form using JToolbarHelper.

I can insert the button to any other component as is and it will submit so I suspect there is something in the way I have created my Form, but after nearly 4 hours I haven't been able to figure it out.

I have tried to create a minimal form for a component (default.php)

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\Language\Text;
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;

$form = JForm::getInstance('query', JPATH_COMPONENT . '/models/forms/query.xml');
?>

<form
    action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_accentis&view=query'); ?>"
    method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="adminForm" id="query-form" >

    <?php echo $form->renderFieldset('query');  ?>

    <input type="hidden" name="task" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name="view" value="query" />
    <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>

</form>
```

My line to add the custom button is (view.html.php)

```
JToolbarHelper::custom('query.loadData', "" , "" , 'Load Data', false);
```

In the console I get this message:

> ```
> TypeError: form is null 2 core-uncompressed.js:66:4
> submitform http://maralinga.test/media/system/js/core-uncompressed.js?0586eb80516116b3723cefdbfa5e045f:66
> submitbutton http://maralinga.test/media/system/js/core-uncompressed.js?0586eb80516116b3723cefdbfa5e045f:99
> onclick http://maralinga.test/administrator/index.php?option=com_accentis&view=query:1
> ```

And around line 66 in the script is where I crash and burn.

```
 * Generic submit form
 *
 * @param  {String}  task      The given task
 * @param  {node}    form      The form element
 * @param  {bool}    validate  The form element
 *
 * @returns  {void}
 */
Joomla.submitform = function(task, form, validate) {

    if (!form) {
        form = document.getElementById('adminForm');
    }

    if (task) {
        form.task.value = task;             <===Line 66
    }
```

I am thinking that the form variable is not getting set correctly and when it gets to line 66 it can't do whatever it wants to do.

I suspect it is something with the way I am creating an instance of my form with the `$form = JForm::getInstance('query', JPATH_COMPONENT . '/models/forms/query.xml');` or in my form definition params.

And I am not sure if it matters, but this is the form object.

```
Joomla\CMS\Form\Form Object
(
    [data:protected] => Joomla\Registry\Registry Object
        (
            [data:protected] => stdClass Object
                (
                )

            [initialized:protected] => 
            [separator] => .
        )

    [errors:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [name:protected] => query
    [options:protected] => Array
        (
            [control] => 
        )

    [xml:protected] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [fieldset] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => query
                            [label] => COM_ACCENTIS_FIELDSET_QUERY
                        )

                    [field] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => searchId
                                            [type] => text
                                            [label] => COM_ACCENTIS_FIELD_SEARCHID_LABEL
                                            [description] => COM_ACCENTIS_FIELD_SEARCHID_DESC
                                            [labelclass] => control-label
                                        )

                                    [0] => 

                                )

                            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => feature
                                            [type] => list
                                            [label] => COM_ACCENTIS_FIELD_FEATURE_LABEL
                                            [description] => COM_ACCENTIS_FIELD_FEATURE_DESC
                                            [labelclass] => control-label
                                        )

                                    [option] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Inventory
                                            [1] => Sales Report
                                        )

                                )

                            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => params
                                            [type] => text
                                            [multiple] => true
                                            [formsource] => administrator/components/com_accentis/models/forms/queryparams.xml
                                            [label] => COM_ACCENTIS_FIELD_PARAMS_LABEL
                                            [description] => COM_ACCENTIS_FIELD_PARAMS_DESC
                                            [labelclass] => control-label
                                        )

                                    [0] => 

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [repeat] => 
)
```

Comment: Try using camel case for your form ID, like so: `<form id="adminForm">`. Currently, you're setting it as `adminform`, with a lowercase `f`

Comment: @Lodder. I have tried with adminForm but no change unfortunately. I have also updated the above post with the change, thanks.

Comment: Charlie's comment is confusing. It's `name` attribute that was `adminform`. The ID is `query-form`. You need to either pass the form to `Joomla.submitform()` or change the ID to `adminForm`.

Comment: @Sharky - Ahh yes, my bad. `name`

Comment: @Sharky, that worked, I have both Name and Id as adminForm and it is now working, thank you. I would have bet the house on me having tried that combination at sometime tonight but thinking about it I might have been all lower case. How would I pass the Form name to Joomla.submitform()? as i saw some of the examples had like id="fred-form" which must have been specified somewhere else.  If you would like to post your reply as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It's name attribute that was adminform. The ID is query-form. You need to either pass the form to Joomla.submitform() or change the ID to adminForm. "   ...@Sharky